# .setAttribute function being used to set rotation for a number of cloned entities

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have cloned an entity several times and now I need to apply a rotation to each one. The rotation for each one is different and stored in an array. How can I assign these rotations?

```
window.onload=function(){


rollRot = document.getElementById("roller-rotation");
rollEl = document.getElementById("roller");
rollCen = document.getElementById("roller-center");
var nElements = 6;
var degSep = 360/nElements;
var rollers = new Array(nElements);
var degRot = 0;

//creat array with rotation data then clone rollerRot
for(var i = 0; i < nElements; i++){

rollers[i] = [{rotation: "0, " + degRot + ", 0"}];

degRot = degRot + degSep;
console.log(degRot);

rollCen.appendChild(rollRot.cloneNode(true));
};
console.log(rollers);
console.log(degSep);
;


//configure rotation

        var rollerNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#roller- 
rotation");
        console.log(rollerNodes);
        rollers.forEach(function(rollersData, index) {
            var rollerItem = rollerNodes[index];

            rollerItem.setAttribute("visible", true);
            rollerItem.setAttribute("rotation:", 
rollersData.rotation); //<----------------
            console.log(rollerItem);
});




}
```

I expect the rotation of the cloned entities to progress somthing like (0, 0, 0) (0, 60, 0) (0 120 0) and so on,

Instead they are all always (0, 0, 0)

Comment: EDIT: the arrays read (0 0 0) (0 60 0) ect. The commas were incorrect. The problem persists however.

Comment: Syntax incorrect. Extra semi colon. It is `setAttribute(“rotation”)` not `setAttribute(“rotation:”)`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that but it still doesn't apply the rotations

Comment: Any reason to clone elements? Use `document.createElement(“a-entity”)` and apply a [mixin](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/mixins.html#sidebar) with the components you need.

Comment: Share [glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe) with minimal code sample that illustrate what you are trying to accomplish. Conversations will be more productive

Comment: Eventually the cloned entities will be gltf files instead of basic geometry. Would mixins still work? and still, how would I apply the array of rotations so that each instance had its unique values?

Comment: this https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/18a7b16e-1b2e-4bb2-880f-228a1366f6b7 is an example of what it should look like if the code was set to nElements = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With syntax like this:

```
rollers[i] = [{rotation: "0, " + degRot + ", 0"}];
```

You're creating an array with an object at `0` inside the rollers array. To access it, you need to do

```
rollers.forEach(function(rollersData, index) {
// ...   
//        rollers item
//       \/         
rollersData[0].rotation
//          /\
//          the inner array with the rotation object
```

like so:

```
rollerItem.setAttribute("rotation", rollersData[0].rotation)
```

---

If it's intentional and you plan to add a position there or whatever its fine, otherwise lose the brackes `[]` to use it like this `rollersData.rotation`.

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2k05f4w/1/).